# How can I merge multiple sprite into one sprite or texture using Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity, unityscript

I have an avatar generator where someone can create a custom avatar with layers superimposed.
And in order to reuse this image multiple times, i want to merge all layers in one image.
Is there any way on unity3D to create this image.

I've already coded that :

```
atlas = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
foreach (Sprite s in allSprite) {
        atlas.SetPixels (0, 0, atlas.width, atlas.height, s.texture.GetPixels (0, 0, atlas.width, atlas.height));
        atlas.Apply ();
}
```

My problem is to keep the transparency and not erase old layers where pixels are transparent. 
The `setPixels` method replace old pixels in `atlas` by new one. 
I can't loop over pixels because of the size of the image (1024*1024) and more than 6 layers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a RTT (render-to-texture) and a custom camera to one-shot render to it to merge all the layers using the GPU.

You can then save and use the resulting texture.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html

If your render texture has alpha then it will maintain the composited alpha values as long as you use the proper separate color-alpha blending mode in the shaders:

```
Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha, OneMinusDstAlpha One
```

If you only need full-size texture blending you can use graphic blit commands to get pixel-aligned full-texture blend (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.Blit.html)

Otherwise you'll need to draw pixel-aligned (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LoadPixelMatrix.html) quads using the GL namespace functions (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html)

Comment: With this method, i think the image will not keep their native resolution and the transparency will be lost. So it will not help me but it's a good approach i think, i'll try something like that

Comment: I added more information on how to achieve this with render textures. **You will be able to keep the images native resolution and the transparency.**

Comment: I find a very helpfull code sample about doing this with RenderTexture here : [link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/super-fast-method-to-create-1-texture-from-multiple-textures.66179/#post-1176312) Thanks for helping me to find the right way do to it.

Comment: I meet with some graphic glitch in trying to use renderTexture on mac ([link](http://vmathieu.fr/pbmRendu.png)), i have already try to change the camera clear flags but it didn't work. So if you have any tips

Comment: Found solution using GL.Clear() to remove glitch.